# Star rating with html and javascript is not working in the right order

Tags: javascript, html, rating

I attempted to create a star rating system using HTML and JavaScript, but it's not functioning properly.

Instead of working from left to right, it works in the opposite direction - from right to left. For instance, if I click on the fourth star, it will color four stars from right to left instead of left to right, so that the first star remains uncolored.

Can anyone advise on how to correct this issue?

```js
function fillStars(num) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var star = document.getElementById('star' + i.toString());
    if (i <= num) {
      star.checked = true;
    } else {
      star.checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rating input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating label::before {
  content: "\2606";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.rating label.checked::before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: gold;
}

.rating label.checked~label::before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: gold;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:checked {
  content: "\2605";
  color: gold;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:checked~label::before {
  content: "\2605";
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-name">
  <fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Bewertung:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" onclick="fillStars(1)" />
    <label for="star1" title="1 Stern"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" onclick="fillStars(2)" />
    <label for="star2" title="2 Sterne"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" onclick="fillStars(3)" />
    <label for="star3" title="3 Sterne"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" onclick="fillStars(4)" />
    <label for="star4" title="4 Sterne"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" onclick="fillStars(5)" />
    <label for="star5" title="5 Sterne"></label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Only _one_ radio button out of a radio button group _can_ be selected at any given time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _"if I click on the fourth star, it will color four stars from right to left instead of left to right"_ - that is not actually what's happening with the code you have shown - https://jsfiddle.net/q318ramf/

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I forgot to share my css. I edit it above

Comment: Your JavaScript function is completely superfluous here - all it does, is set the radio button that was _already_ checked (because the user clicked it), to checked again. The coloring of the stars, is based purely on CSS. `input[type="radio"]:checked~label` selects _all_ the labels, that come _after_ the checked radio button. CSS can't select in the "other" direction.

Comment: So to get this to work properly, you need to a) change the order of your radio buttons in the HTML - needs start with 5, going down to 1; and b) reverse the _visual_ order again, by using `flex-direction: row-reverse;` on the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace below code in css:

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `for` loop doesn't make much sense, as only one `radio` element of the group can be checked. You could remove this snippet altogether. Labels are enough to make the correct radio element clickable.

Then, you need to think about the CSS. You want to make everything *after* the checked radio element an empty star, so the input would need to go *after* a star.